# Weird issue with MySQL with unexpected results

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table for reporting, the engine is innoDB, and there is some partitionning : /*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH ( YEAR(date) * 12 + MONTH(date))
PARTITIONS 48 */

The table has a date field, a dealId field, a placementId field (and some metrics columns).

I have a dealId which is present for date 2017-09-10 :

```
select count(*) from report_deal_plac where date = "2017-09-10" and dealId = 11983;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       96 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I try to get all dealId for this date, I can't find this dealId :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(dealId) FROM report_deal_plac WHERE date = "2017-09-10";
+--------+
| dealId |
+--------+
|   1938 |
|   3620 |
|   5892 |
|   6360 |
|   6814 |
|   8928 |
|   9010 |
|   9193 |
|   9282 |
|   9583 |
|   9676 |
|  10129 |
|  10300 |
|  10615 |
|  10858 |
|  11259 |
|  11388 |
|  11563 |
+--------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried using group by, in case I had an issue with distinct, but it doesn't help :

```
SELECT dealId FROM report_deal_plac WHERE date = "2017-09-10" group by dealId;
+--------+
| dealId |
+--------+
|   1938 |
|   3620 |
|   5892 |
|   6360 |
|   6814 |
|   8928 |
|   9010 |
|   9193 |
|   9282 |
|   9583 |
|   9676 |
|  10129 |
|  10300 |
|  10615 |
|  10858 |
|  11259 |
|  11388 |
|  11563 |
+--------+
```

Using a where clause doesn't help either :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(dealId) FROM report_deal_plac WHERE date = "2017-09-10" and dealId = 11983;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I did a CHECK TABLE which says it's OK. I tried an OPTIMIZE table (which did recreate + analyze instead, and had an OK result). But this doesn't help.

Where could the issue come from ?

Here is the table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE `report_deal_plac` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `dealId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `placementId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `impressions` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `impressionsKept` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `impressionsResold` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dollarRevenue` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `revenue` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `netDollarRevenue` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `netRevenue` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `impressionsMeasured` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `impressionsViewed` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `impressionsSoldMeasured` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `impressionsSoldViewed` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `clicks` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`,`dealId`,`placementId`),
  KEY `dealid` (`dealId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH ( YEAR(date) * 12 + MONTH(date))
PARTITIONS 48 */
```

Here is the EXPLAIN PARTITIONS for my query

```
explain partitions select DISTINCT(dealId) FROM report_deal_plac WHERE date = '2017-09-10';
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+----------------+--------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type  | possible_keys  | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+----------------+--------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | report_deal_plac | p21        | range | PRIMARY,dealid | dealid | 4       | NULL |  533 | Using where; Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+-------+----------------+--------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------------+
```

UPDATE : For an epilogue to this :

- Using `BETWEEN '2017-09-10' AND '2017-09-11'` worked (there were no data at all for the 11th). I have no idea why. (And `BETWEEN '2017-09-10' AND '2017-09-10'` didn't work)
- Using an aggregate function with the `GROUP BY` worked
- `SET optimizer_switch = 'index_merge_intersection=off';` didn't do anything
- `REPAIR` or `ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;` didn't change anything

All the dealIds I was getting were the ones where I only had one line for the date in the table.

I fixed the issue by creating another table with the exact same name and doing an `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table`, truncating the old table, and re inserting from the new one.

Comment: What's your MySQL version?  Is it an InnoDB table?  Tried testing with a non-partitioned table?  Got the query cache enabled?

Comment: And can we have the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for it too?

Comment: I added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Yes this is an innoDB table. I haven't tried with a non-partitioned table. I think query cache is enabled. But a SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT(dealId) has the same result. Version is : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.37, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: What happens if you use `BETWEEN '2017-09-09' AND '2017-09-11'`? What about `SELECT MAX(date) = '2017-09-10' FROM report_deal_plac WHERE dealId= 11983 and date = '2017-09-10'`?

Comment: I used `BETWEEN '2017-09-10' AND '2017-09-11'` and I get the expected result (I have no data for the 11th). Using only the 10 for the second date gives me the result from my question. This is a good pointer, thanks ! Even if I still don't understand the result with a simple WHERE...

Comment: Try running `RESET QUERY CACHE` and then running your original query.

Comment: Reseting the query cache doesn't help

Comment: Can you add the `explain partitions` output? Since you have an index on `dealId` too, and this seems to not happen with a range scan, this might be a bug with partitioning and index merge/index intersection. You could try to disable index merge with `SET optimizer_switch = 'index_merge_intersection=off';`

Comment: @Solarflare I added the explain partitions. I tried disabling index merge, but this doesn't change anything about my output.

Comment: It's not using the index merge here, so disabling did not fix it. Partitioning unfortunately has some unspecific bugs, so it was just a guess, but I still think it has to do with your index on dialid. You could try to use the primary key (which could actually be even better for your query depending on placementId), so try e.g. `select DISTINCT(dealId) FROM report_deal_plac force index (primary) WHERE date = '2017-09-10';` (and check `explain partitions` if it uses the primary key). This might btw be the reason Jacques solution works (so check the explain for which index it uses).

Comment: I ended up rebuilding the table from scratch and the issue has fixed itself. I cannot reproduce the issue now, so I won't really be able to test anything else much. I updated my post with the different solutions I tried

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `COUNT` of each value. There could be multiple rows with `dealId = 11983`

```
SELECT dealId, count(*)
FROM report_deal_plac
WHERE date = "2017-09-10"
group by dealId;
```

You should see the result you are looking for

Comment: This indeed gives me the expected result. But why ? I can see that without the count(*), I only get lines that has only one rows. But why would group by behaves this way ? Is there something I can read about it ?

Comment: And now that I rebuilt the table, I don't need the `COUNT` to get all results

Comment: GROUP BY is *supposed* to hide replicated details - So is distinct. So a count shows you the number of things hidden. As to why rebuilding show up all the results ... IDK :-/